How to link freeglut and glew on Raspberry Pi using CMake?
I'm working with an OpenGL on Raspberry Pi OS and I'm using freeglut and glew as a window manager.
I'm using CMake to build and link the project.
I've installed freeglut3-dev and libglew2.2, libglew-dev using apt. But can't figure out how to properly link them to my project.
I'm using Raspberry Pi 5
I've tried find_package() with different names but didn't succeed.
I wanted to manually include the .h files, but it didn't help either
